Why do my transactions, using sendRawTransaction, often times out in 30 seconds?
transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
            //console.log(`transaction.recentBlockhash: ${transaction.recentBlockhash}`)

            // Sign the transaction
            transaction.sign(payer);
            console.log("sign")

            // Send the transaction
            let signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize());
            console.log("Transaction sent with signature:", signature);

            // Confirm the transaction
            let confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'confirmed');
            console.log("Transaction confirmed:", confirmation);
            // const rep = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer])
            // console.log(rep)

Sometimes it times out in 30 seconds, and sometimes it takes more than ten seconds and then is confirmed successfully. Is there any way to improve the speed?

is there a noticable differrence when using the normal sendTransaction

I would recommend using a private RPC provider like Helius or Triton if you are using the public RPC endpoint.
Even though raw transactions might seem reasonable when sending transactions, external factors such as latency, network load ....

I used helius to create a free key. Is this ok? I have already done this, but it still times out frequently.

Yes. The free key has limitations. It's also depends on what you're doing. If you are generating profit, get a dedicated RPC node from them. Ultra expensive but worth it IMO.

Also, don't spam with tx happening one after the others add timeouts if you are calling txs continuosly
